# How do I find the question I posted?

Tags: support

I posted a question, received some answers, but closed it and cannot find it again. Can you tell me how I find a question I already posted?

Comment: Your profile page - http://stackoverflow.com/users/5194589/k-hill?tab=questions

Comment: That's it downvote the new users because they should just know how to use everything

Comment: @James True, but that doesn't mean he shouldn't have figured it out. SO works like all other websites on the internet - you'll find the most inportant things less than a minute, and all contents you've made are aviable under your profile. I don't like questions that you can answer yourself faster than you ask them.

Comment: @klenium  [Support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) "*A request for assistance with one of the site's features.*" I very much doubt a search would be possible to find out such a simple low level request. IMO this question is not doing any harm at all, a user just wanted some help, and there is no reason for so many downvotes.

Comment: @James While I argee with you, and I'm happy to help anyone, for new users it's sometimes better to learn how the site works, and search before asking. Not because we don't want to answer a question line "how do I open my browser?", they'll save a lot of time if they know where the most important things are, and how a typical website works. It's about logic. That's why we learn things in the school that we'll never need to use.

Comment: @klenium I get what you're saying, but the problem is not a general one, it's this question's request specifically. The keywords required in a search would include words such as "question", "posted", "answered", "previously posted" - such a search would just return unrelated results, and there's no way a new user would have *found* this info themselves.

Answer (score 8):

You can find your question, answers and other activities on your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions) as indicated by [bluefeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet)

or

You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq) for your questions by typing `user:me is:q` in the search box at right top corner. Once executed you find the *Advanced Search Tips* link  at the right hand side of the screen. Near the bottom you find a link to the [help topic on searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

If you are looking for your deleted posts, look for the link called [`deleted recent questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5194589) at the bottom of the Answer or Questions list of your profile, which gives you those created no more than 60 days ago.

Comment: This is great, but where on the net did you find this info?  This is a totally not findable option.  What would indicate that this is an option?  Are there any other flags that can be used?

Comment: I added that to the answer @Adrian but you will be looking for the help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching and once you searched, the right hand side of the screen under *advanced search tips* as a handy list with often used search operators. I might have found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) earlier.

Comment: Thanks.  Still not really that discoverable unless you know where to look or go outside of site.  Would be nice that if focus was brought to the search box, it would automatically dropdown an advanced link.

Comment: @Adrian some features remain a mystery after years even for me. But with your recent experience and my guidance maybe you see how the discover-ability can be improved. I don't know from the top of my head if that is proposed before but if you see fit and can't find anything else, feel free to suggest anything (something that is actionable) to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

To search among all your activity (including questions) in 'all' the networks, use the StackExchange activity page:

1. go to https://stackexchange.com
2. go to your profile
3. in the tab bar, choose 'activity'
4. then choose 'posts'

[image: StackExchange website]